# Prerendering a blazor webassembly website .net standard 2.1 fails

Tags: blazor, webassembly, prerender

I have a blazor server project .NET core 3.1 and a blazor web client project .NET Standard 2.1.
The server project should prerender the web client but I keep getting execption on blazor.config not found.  Even when I create such a file and add the required info I still get an error.

Any idea where I can find an up to date sample project or an idea how I can get this to work ?

Application always throws exception on this line : app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<webclient.Program>();

Exception:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'C:\Users\thoma\Downloads\blzRdr\blzRdr2\blzAppTest\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\dist'

Thanks

Comment: Try upgrading to .NET5, and follow the MS guidance on setting the server project accordingly, there was a setting on the component tag 9n host.cshtml that I can't remember off the top of my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upgrade to Net5.
2. `UseClientSideBlazor` is obselete.  use

```
 app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
```

3. Your `_Host.cshtml` file should look something like:

```
.....
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <app>
            <component type="typeof(mylibrary.App)" render-mode="Static" />
        </app>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`<app>...</app>` preloads a static server built version of the page, then once  WebAssembly is loaded, it reloads the live page into `<div id="app">....</div>` replacing the existing content.